# Headphones not working on Asus G751JT laptop

Tags: headphones

When I plug in my headphones on Asus G751JT laptop with 16.04 LTS no sound is coming out of them while sound continues to play from laptop speakers.

Here are my Alsa details:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=6d358e8b683771d1ac039b8b9a09075c2bb61b84

Headphones work fine in preinstalled Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Dell Latitude E7450.

It's not my favourite solution, but here's what's working for me for now:

Install indicator-sound-switcher:

http://yktoo.com/en/software/indicator-sound-switcher

Then you can at least manually switch.  For some reason, pulseaudio doesn't automatically switch the sink when the headphones are connected.

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it didnt work as headphones arent even detected on my system, they are not present in any mixer and this indicator doesnt show them either, I managed to get sound from them by editing alsabase.conf, but I get sound from speakers at the same time.

Comment: Now that you got them both working, the output may show up.  Check with either the above indicator or pavucontrol (sudo apt install pavucontrol first)

Comment: With further hacking is shows headphones in pavucontrol but there is no sound and volume is not muted or low.